# PowerShell and Task<T> in .NET

Tags: .net, powershell, asynchronous, task

It appears that PowerShell always waits for the completion when you ask it to display a `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<T>` type, regardless of whether `Task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` is called or not.

Is this behavior documented anywhere?

I have these methods in a DLL:

```cs
public static class MyClass {
    public static async Task AsyncSleep() =>
        await Task.Run(() => System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000));
    public static Task NonAsyncSleep() =>
        Task.Run(() => System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000));
    public static Task<string> NonAsyncSleepStr() =>
        Task.Run(() => { System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); return "asd"; });
}
```

When called from a PowerShell session:

- `[MyClass]::AsyncSleep()` always blocks with or without `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`.
- `[MyClass]::NonAsyncSleep()` only blocks when followed by `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`.
- `[MyClass]::NonAsyncSleepStr()` always blocks with or without `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`.

I was expecting all 3 methods to be non-blocking (i.e. returns immediately) when called without `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`. Since both `AsyncSleep` and `NonAsyncSleepStr` returns **Task`1** type  in PowerShell and `NonAsyncSleep` returns **Task**, can we assume that PowerShell would wait no matter what when the return type is Task (i.e. contains some sort of result)?

Is this another quirk of PowerShell (like the one with array unwrapping)?

Comment: First post your Powershell code. Second, all the methods are *blocking*. `Thread.Sleep()` blocks and puts the thread to sleep. Using `Task.Run` only means you're putting a background thread to sleep. Use `Task.Delay` for a really async method. Finally, Powershell supports concurrency out of the box by executing each step in a pipeline in a different thread. Each step receives a *stream* of inputs, processes it and emits a stream of outputs to the next step. This is similar to how Dataflow classes work

Comment: In Powershell, threads are managed by the runtime/pipeline. Messages are passed between cmdlets/steps by the runtime. Commandlets don't have to know or care about threads. If you search the [PowerShell Github Repo](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/17fb783736d98608cefe4a505c48901e63ba10f6/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility/commands/utility/WebCmdlet/Common/WebRequestPSCmdlet.Common.cs#L1258) you'll find that even commands like `Invoke-WebRequest` use `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`. The entire concurrency model is *very* different from C# but *very* similar to all other shells